# Why does D3 Brush Not Clear Multiple Graphs in React App

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have multiple graphs being displayed on the same page in different elements within the same React Component. Each graph uses the same bit of code, but only the 1st graph clears the Brush after a selection. All graphs work fine in a regular `js` file without React.

```
const plotArea = async (props: any) => {
    ...

    // Handler for the end of a brush event from D3.
    const brushEnded = (event: any) => {
      const s = event.selection;
      // Consume the brush action
      if (s) {
        d3.select('.brush').call(brush.move, null);
      }
    }

    // Create a brush for selecting regions to zoom on.
    const brush: any = d3
      .brushX()
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height - 1],
      ])
      .on('end', brushEnded);

    // Zoom brush
    svg.append('g').attr('class', 'brush').call(brush);
}


useEffect(() => {
    // plotArea() occurs for each graph, there are multiple graphs
    plotArea(...);
    ...

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When d3 runs the selection in `d3.select('.brush').call(brush.move, null);`, it does not limit the search to the component. It will search the whole document for a `.brush` element, and will stop as soon as it finds the first.

As a quick fix, you can save the specific brush of the component, so that you already have the reference and don't need to run a `d3.select` to get it back:

```js
const plotArea = async (props: any) => {
    ...

    // Create brushElement first
    const brushElement = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'brush');
    
    // Handler for the end of a brush event from D3.
    const brushEnded = (event: any) => {
      const s = event.selection;
      // Consume the brush action
      if (s) {
        brushElement.call(brush.move, null); // Now uses the variable
      }
    }

    // Create a brush for selecting regions to zoom on.
    const brush: any = d3
      .brushX()
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height - 1],
      ])
      .on('end', brushEnded);

    
    brushElement.call(brush);

}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I thought the `select` on a class would actually grab all the instances. This makes a lot more sense now and works perfectly.